# pecl install mongo command for mongo-1.5.5.tgz produce invalid tgz error

Tags: mongodb, docker

## Overview

I was creating my Docker image to setup Rockmongo. 
In the Dockerfile, I have a command

```
pecl install mongo
```

This command was working before but when ran t today I am getting this error,

```
downloading mongo-1.5.5.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.5.5.tgz (Unknown size)
....done: 3,582 bytes
Could not get contents of package "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.10/pear-build-download/mongo-1.5.5.tgz". Invalid tgz file.
Download of "pecl/mongo" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/mongo"
```

## Reference

To view the whole docker file
   https://github.com/gilacode/docker-rockmongo/blob/master/Dockerfile

## Question

Is there any way to specificy a different version of the Mongo package during the "pecl install command"?

Comment: There would appear to be an issue with the pecl site right now and content is not being properly delivered. You can always wait or pull the [source directly from github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver). If you can live with a git client as an additional dependency then you can build and install this way.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn, I am not sure I want to add git client in my Docker container. I guess I will wait till the site is up.

Answer (score 3):

I see this is an old question but anyway ...
I had the same issue and it was not due to the pecl website.
It seems to be a bug with the "lfs" option when you compile php5.
To verify if this is your case type: php-config --phpapi

I got it working by adding the --nocompress option
[sudo pecl install --nocompress mongo]

You can see other details here https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67075

Comment: I had this issue on 32 bits machine and was solved with "sudo pecl install --nocompress mongo"