# Installing mongoDB PHP driver on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, pecl

I'm issues installing the mongo PHP driver in OS X Yosemite.  I had it installed and configured in Mavericks.  This is what I get in the terminal:

```
$ sudo pecl install mongo
Password:
/usr/local/bin/pecl: line 28: /usr/local/bin/php: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/pecl: line 28: exec: /usr/local/bin/php: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I have Xcode installed and updated, along with the command line tools.  Has Pecl changed with Yosemite, or has anyone else run into the same issue?

Comment: do you have php in your system ? what is the result of "php -v " command ? or the "which php"

Comment: PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25)
    Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your pecl installed with different php.
you can make a soft link by using ln :

```
ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php
```

Comment: Creating the soft-link worked.  However, when I ran sudo pecl install mongo, I got this error:                                                                                                       downloading mongo-1.6.3.tgz ...
Starting to download mongo-1.6.3.tgz (204,130 bytes)
...........................................done: 204,130 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/private/tmp/pear/download/mongo-1.6.3.tgz"
Download of "pecl/mongo" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/mongo"
Download failed
install failed

Comment: try ----nocompress option [sudo pecl install --nocompress mongo]  as the link below suggests :                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590621/pecl-install-mongo-command-for-mongo-1-5-5-tgz-produce-invalid-tgz-error